# How does java manage hashmap size allocations that would cause it to perform poorly?

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashtable, hashcode

For example if I allocate a Hashmap of size 100, and if 100 buckets get created then wouldn't the Hashmap perform poorly? (As performing modular hashing will not distribute the keys evenly in all of the 100 buckets)

How does java manage this problem? Does it randomly choose a prime near 100 to be the Hashmap size ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can you can see in the [sources](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html), it chooses the next biggest power of two (line 197 ff):

```
       // Find a power of 2 >= initialCapacity
       int capacity = 1;
       while (capacity < initialCapacity)
           capacity <<= 1;

       this.loadFactor = loadFactor;
       threshold = (int)(capacity * loadFactor);
       table = new Entry[capacity];
```